# How to filter data of one API response using data from another API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am using the Spotify API and want to display only playlists that have a matching playlist ID to the (mock) playlist ID stored in my database.

```
const [playlistsData, setPlaylistsData] = useState(null);
const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState(null);
```

playlist ID stored in my database:

```
    const [myPlaylistId, setMyPlaylistId] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    getPlaylistId();
  }, []);

  const getPlaylistId = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5001/myplaylists");
    const id = await response.json();
    setMyPlaylistId(id);
  };

     // returns: 
    // 0: {id: 1, playlist_id: '34i9Keonvl7HaVKh3Y5S0G'}
   // 1: {id: 2, playlist_id: '37i9dQZF1DX4dyzvuaRJ0n'}
```

Fetching all of the playlists of the current user using API

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const { data } = await getCurrentUserPlaylists();
        setPlaylistsData(data);
    };

    catchErrors(fetchData());
}, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!playlistsData) {
      return;
    }

    const fetchMoreData = async () => {
      if (playlistsData.next) {
        const { data } = await axios.get(playlistsData.next);
        setPlaylistsData(data);
      }
    };

      setPlaylists((playlists) => [
        ...(playlists ? playlists : []),
        ...playlistsData.items,
      ]);


    // Fetch next set of playlists as needed
    catchErrors(fetchMoreData());
  }, [playlistsData]);

//Spotify API Call returns (abbreviated) 
100:{ 
collaborative: false
description: ""
id: "37i9dQZF1DX4dyzvuaRJ0n"
}
```

And the webpage returns:

```
  return (
    <main>
      <SectionWrapper>
        {playlists && <PlaylistsGrid playlists={playlists} />}
      </SectionWrapper>
    </main>
  );
```

My goal here is to only return the playlists called from Spotify's API that have a matching id to those being called from my database.

I've tried countless potential solves but none have worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
setPlaylists((playlists) => [
    ...(playlists ? playlists : []),
    ...playlistsData.items,
  ]);
```

Here you just have to add below playlist_id in the new array and when you setPlaylists you need to check if the playlistsData.id includes (contains) in the new array

```
 returns: 
 0: {id: 1, playlist_id: '34i9Keonvl7HaVKh3Y5S0G'}
1: {id: 2, playlist_id: '37i9dQZF1DX4dyzvuaRJ0n'}
```

Hope this is clear if i have understood your question correctly.

Comment: Would you mind being more specific? I understand your logic but don't understand your intended implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to filter two arrays with common element, these are some of the possible solutions i can think of

1. use filter and indexOf methods of array

```
var array = [1,2,3,4];
var anotherOne = [2,4];
var filteredArray = array.filter((el) => anotherOne.indexOf(el) < 0 );
```

2. if you are using lodash.js.

```
filteredArray = _.difference(array, anotherOne);
```

Comment: The API responses have different keys and different number of keys (i.e., one response returns 10 keys and the other 2). Although this does work, I am looking for clarity on my particular situation.